# Pyside6: Dynamically add points to chart view

Tags: python, graph, pyside

I want to make an application that put a random point on a graph every 5 seconds but it does not update when I append the point to the line series. I also tried the repaint() and QApplication.ProcessEvent() but still does not update.

here's my code

```
import random
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChartView, QChart, QLineSeries


class MyGraph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.points = []

        # Set up the graph
        self.point_line_series = QLineSeries()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(self.point_line_series)
        self.chart.setTitle("Points Over Time")
        self.chart_view = QChartView()
        self.chart_view.setChart(self.chart)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart_view)

        # Start a timer to add new points every 5 seconds
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.add_point)
        self.timer.start(5000)

    def add_point(self):
        x = random.randint(0, 100)
        y = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.points.append((x, y))
        self.point_line_series.append(x, y)
        print(f"added point {x}, {y}")
        self.repaint()
        self.chart_view.repaint()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    graph = MyGraph()
    graph.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I want to add points every 5 seconds and update the graph.

The graph does not update but the points is appended to the line series.

Answer (score 0):

here's the workaround

```
import random
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChartView, QChart, QLineSeries


class MyGraph(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.points = []

        # Set up the graph
        self.point_line_series = QLineSeries()
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(self.point_line_series)
        chart.setTitle("Points Over Time")
        self.chart_view = QChartView()
        self.chart_view.setChart(chart)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.chart_view)

        # Start a timer to add new points every 5 seconds
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.add_point)
        self.timer.start(5000)

    def add_point(self):
        x = random.randint(0, 100)
        y = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.points.append((x, y))
        self.point_line_series.append(x, y)
        print(f"added point {x}, {y}")
        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(self.point_line_series)
        self.chart_view.setChart(chart)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    graph = MyGraph()
    graph.show()
    app.exec_()
```

basically just make a new chart add the line series and set that chart as the chart of chart view using chart.setchart()